# How to display comma separated value in Easy Admin bundle Symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

Where categories is multiple category collection?

```
fields:
 - { property: 'categories' }
```

I have try many type but still i am not able to display comma separated value, By default it is displaying number of items in array collection

thanks for help !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should change your code as per below to display comma separated value in easy admin:

```
fields:
  { property: 'categories', type: 'array' }
```

If you will not add property `type: 'array'`, then easy admin will display total number of items in array or array collection.